# Loop through all Appointments in calendar

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

Is it possible to loop through each appointment in the main calendar and retrieve all their details like subject ect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I managed to do this just a few days ago. Below is my code on how I did it. First of all you must get the calendar folder, then create a view of a group of appointments on the calendar in that folder. You can then so a search on the folder for all appointments and loop through them.

```
Appointment existingAppointment = null;

DateTime startDate = (DateTime.Now).AddDays(-30);
DateTime endDate = (DateTime.Now).AddDays(60);
const int NUM_APPTS = 9999999;

Mailbox mb = new Mailbox("youremail@email.com"); 

FolderId calendarsFolder = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, mb);

CalendarFolder calendarFolder = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, calendarsFolder);

// Set the calendar view as 30 days before dateTimeNow and 60 days after
CalendarView calendarView = new CalendarView(startDate, endDate, NUM_APPTS);

// Set the appointment properties for the calendar view search
PropertySet prop = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, extendedPropertyEventID)
    {ItemSchema.ItemClass,
    ItemSchema.Id,
    ItemSchema.Subject,
    AppointmentSchema.Subject,
    };
calendarView.PropertySet = prop;

// Search for all appointments in the main calendar folder
FindItemsResults<Appointment> findAppointmentsResults = calendarFolder.FindAppointments(calendarView);

// Loop through all the appointments in view
foreach (Appointment appointment in findAppointmentsResults)
{
    // Do stuff with the appointment
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try reading -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633700%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx 
you need to create a search filter

```
searchFilter.SearchFilterCollection searchFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection();
searchFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(AppointmentSchema.Start, new DateTime(1999, 1, 1)));
```

create an item view

```
ItemView view = new ItemView(20);
view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, AppointmentSchema.Subject, AppointmentSchema.Start, AppointmentSchema.AppointmentType);
```

send the request

```
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, searchFilter, view);
```

Loop through the results

```
foreach (Item item in findResults.Items)
{
    Appointment appt = item as Appointment;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :) I wish I could set you both as the answer lol

Comment: no problem, Alex Harveys answer is the better one, as its targeted directly at your question, mine is more "abstract" so to speak :) good luck